# Detecting if any cell is being edited in a JTable

Tags: java, jtable

I have a JTable in which users can edit cells.   When the user is through editing the cell, I want to enable a button that allows the user to validate the input.    However, I only want to do this when the user is no longer in edit mode.    Is there an easy way for me to detect if any cell in a Jtable is currently being edited?

Thank you,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even easier:

```
if (!table.isEditing())
   //
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the Jtable has a way to detect if any cell is being edited.    It is actually very simple.    You simply check if myJtable.getCellEditor() == null.   If it is not, you are editing a cell, if it is, no cells are being edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TableEditor extends DefaultCellEditor{
JTextField com;

  public TableEditor(){
  getComponent().addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
      com.setBackground(new Color.red);
    }
   });
  }
}
```

And then

```
tb.setDefaultEditor(Object.class,new TableEditor());
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use a custom `TabelModel` and override the `setValueAt` function to perform your validation. It should automatically be called whenever a user is done editing a table cell.